How do replace urls and youtube urls and replaces the urls as anchor tags and replace youtube urls as Iframe tags
Say if the string returns:
str = `
            https://www.google.com
            http://google.com
            https://www.youtube.com/live/gNIQWYgf-0
            https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr
            https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj
            this also has to take into account the variations of different youtube urls

      `

so when this string comes back I want to wrap the anchor tags for:
<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
<a href="https://google.com">https://www.google.com</a>

and wrap the YouTube with iframe tags:
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr"></iframe>

How can I achieve this, what I have tried:
  const redExpYoutube = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|\?v=|watch\?v=|&v=)([^#&?]*).*/;
  const regExpUrl = /(www+\.)?(?!youtube?!youtu.be)([\w-]+s{0,3})[/\.,;:!]{1,3}\s{0,3}(r[o0]|n[e3]t|lt|c[o0]m|[i!]nf[o0]|[o0]rg|b[i!][z2]|ru|[e3]du)(\/)?/g;

    embeddedString = str.replace(regExpUrl, "<a style='text-decoration:underline;color:red;' href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
    
    console.log("1: " + embeddedString);

    embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(redExpYoutube, "<iframe src='https://$1$2/$3'></iframe>");
    
    embeddedString = embeddedString.replace(/<[\/]{0,1}(div)[^><]*>/g,"");
    
    console.log("2: " + embeddedString);

UPADTE

Update after Brett Donald answered but did not include the full scenario:
 str = `
            <div>https://www.google.com</div>
            <div><span>http://google.com</span></div>
            <div>https://www.youtube.com/live/gNIQWYgf-0</div>
            <div>https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr</div>
            <div>https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj</div>
            this also has to take into account the variations of different youtube urls

      `

So the URLs will be wrapped around other elements as well as the YouTube URLs will have other elements wrapped around them.
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}   style={{ flex: 1, }}>
                        <RichEditor style={{ flex: 1, }}
                        
                        placeholder="Enter Comment..."
                            ref={richText}
                            initialContentHTML={editorHtml }
                            onChange ={ (txt)=> {editorOnChange(txt)}}
                        />
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

const editorOnChange = (txt) => {
    embeddedString = linkify(txt);
    console.log("2: " + embeddedString);
  }

UPDATE

I am using a WebView now to send data from WebView to react native call-back and do the manipulating there.
Im using the function in React native now and using a webview to pass the data back to the React native app and do the url manipulation there using window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(content);
<WebView 
    onMessage={(event) => {

        
        editorOnChange(event.nativeEvent.data);
      }}
    
    source={{
            html: `

                    
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
                            
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <style>
                                [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
                                    content: attr(data-text);
                                    cursor: text;
                                    color: red;
                                    pointer-events:none;
                                }

                                #placeholder{
                                    position:absolute;
                                    
                                    color:#BDBDBD;font-size:46px;outline:none;
                                }
                                #contentHtml{
                                    position:absolute;
                                    color:black;font-size:46px;outline:none;width:100%;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <div id="contentHtml" contenteditable=true>
                            </div>
                            <div id="placeholder">
                                Enter Comment...
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    <script>
                        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
                            $("#placeholder").on("click", function(){
                                $("#contentHtml").focus();
                                $(this).hide();
                            })        
                        
                            $("#contentHtml").on("input", function(){
                                var content = $(this).text();
                                window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(content);
                                if($(this).html().length === 0){
                                    $("#placeholder").show();
                                } else {
                                    $("#placeholder").hide();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        
                    </script>
                    
                    `,
        }}
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            fontSize:46,
        }}>



    </WebView>

This call-back in react native
  const editorOnChange = (txt) => {
    convertLinks(txt);
    //console.log(convertLinks(txt));
  }

This is the function that Brett Donald suggested to look at:
const convertLinks = ( input ) => {

    let text = input;
    const linksFound = text.match( /(?:www|http?|https?)[^\s]+/g );
    const aLink = [];
    console.log(linksFound);
    if ( linksFound != null ) {
  
      for ( let i=0; i<linksFound.length; i++ ) {
        let replace = linksFound[i];
        if ( !( linksFound[i].match( /(http(s?)):\/\// ) ) ) { replace = 'http://' + linksFound[i] }
        let linkText = replace.split( '/' )[2];
        if ( linkText.substring( 0, 3 ) == 'www' ) { linkText = linkText.replace( 'www.', '' ) }
        if ( linkText.match( /youtu/ ) ) {
  
          let youtubeID = replace.split( '/' ).slice(-1)[0];
          aLink.push( '<div class="video-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeID + '" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>' )
        }
        else if ( linkText.match( /vimeo/ ) ) {
          let vimeoID = replace.split( '/' ).slice(-1)[0];
          aLink.push( '<div class="video-wrapper"><iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + vimeoID + '" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe></div>' )
        }
        else {
          aLink.push( '<a href="' + replace + '" target="_blank">' + linkText + '</a>' );
        }
        text = text.split( linksFound[i] ).map(item => { return aLink[i].includes('iframe') ? item.trim() : item } ).join( aLink[i] );
      }
      return text;
  
    }
    else {
      return input;
    }
  }

but when the linkify function is called the matches are concatenating here ["https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTfhttp://www.google.comhGhy"], i cant seem to understand how to split the two matches. this line const linksFound = text.match( /(?:www|http?|https?)[^\s]+/g );
UPDATE

I found how to split the urls using text.match( /(?:www|http?|https?)[^\s]+/img )
But now the urls are wrapping correctly, but the result is leaving empty spaces like this:
  ["http://www.google.com", "https://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf"]
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">google.com</a> 
  <div class="video-wrapper"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/em
  
    
  
  ---all this empty space---
  
    
  
 
  
                                                                                                                                      
   mbed/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf" frameborder="0" 
   allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; 
   picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>


Where is this string coming from? Why does it contain a bunch of links wrapped inside <div> elements? Please edit your question to include some background information to help us understand the big picture. Why are we doing this?

Obligatory link about the futility of trying to parse (X)HTML with regexes

its comming from react-native-pell-rich-editor

I want the editor because I want to allow emojis and YouTube URLs and standard URLs, so when I return the html I can output the html using maybe the react-native-htmlview

You need to start with some good linkify code, and build up a solution from there. I’ve written a basic formatYouTube() function here, which you can extend to cater for more scenarios.


const linkify = t => {
  const isValidHttpUrl = s => {
    let u
    try {u = new URL(s)}
    catch (_) {return false}
    return u.protocol.startsWith("http")
  }
  const formatYouTube = u => {
    if (!u.includes('youtu')) return null
    if (u.includes('youtu.be'))
      return `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${u.match(/[^\/]*$/)[0]}`
    return u
  }
  const m = t.match(/(?<=\s|^)[a-zA-Z0-9-:/]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-].+?(?=[.,;:?!-]?(?:\s|$))/g)
  if (!m) return t
  const a = []
  m.forEach(x => {
    const [t1, ...t2] = t.split(x)
    a.push(t1)
    t = t2.join(x)
    const y = (!(x.match(/:\/\//)) ? 'https://' : '') + x
    if (isNaN(x) && isValidHttpUrl(y)) {
      const z = formatYouTube(y)
      if (z)
        a.push('<iframe src="' + z + '"></iframe>')
      else
        a.push('<a href="' + y + '" target="_blank">' + y.split('/')[2] + '</a>')
    }
    else
      a.push(x)
  })
  a.push(t)
  return a.join('')
}

const b = document.querySelector('button')
const ta = document.querySelector('textarea')
const o = document.querySelector('.output')

b.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  o.innerHTML = linkify(ta.innerHTML).replaceAll('\n','<br>')
})
body, textarea, button {
  font-family: monospace;
}
body {
  margin: 1em;
  background: silver;
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  height: 9em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white; 
}
iframe {
  margin: 1em; 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<textarea>
one two three microsoft.com four five six
https://www.google.com or http://google.com
https://www.youtube.com/live/gNIQWYgf-0
https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr
https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj
</textarea>
<button>Linkify</button>
<div class="output"></div>



After running this snippet, use the full page link to see things properly.

Hi @Brett Donald, thanks for looking into this, i tried your solution and did not work, I think its my fault as I didn't explain the real scenario. The str will have other elements around the URLs. I have updated the scenario again. Please accept my apologies.

Yeah, so that potentially makes it more difficult. The linkify code on which I based my solution was built to take a plain text input containing links, rather than an HTML input containing links. But it might still work.

no luck with the html elements arround the urls. I get this output:
http://google.comhttps://youtu.be/75fDo2yk6RM?si=QxkLmcT_TiIgHiTf
i think my best bet is to use a webview and make the context editable to true
